# PDO update two tables at once

Tags: php

I am trying to update two tables at once when form is submited.
http://pastebin.com/ctmaWWN8

Beside updating the **article_cat** table, I also need to update **article_posts** table.
In **article_posts** table I need to set **cat** to what ever I have typed in the form.

```
UPDATE article_posts SET cat=:cat WHERE cat=:cat
```

Something like that I guess, but I don't know how to combine them together!

Here is my PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$cat = $_POST['cat'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$sqlInsert = 'UPDATE article_cat SET cat=:cat, name=:name WHERE id=:id';
$preparedStatement = $db->prepare($sqlInsert);
$preparedStatement->execute(array(':cat' => $cat, ':name' => $name, ':id' => $id));

if (empty($name)) {
// do something
    echo'<div class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>Categorys name field is Empty!</div>';
    }
    elseif (empty($cat)) {
        echo'<div class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>Categorys short name field is Empty!</div>';
    }
    else {



    if ($preparedStatement->execute())
{
  echo'<div class="alert-box success"><span>success: </span>Category Updated!</div>';
}
// If execution failed then ->
else
{

 echo'<div class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>Something went wrong while updating Category :/ ! Please try again.</div>';
}



    }

}
```

Comment: Place `$pdo->closeCursor()` after each `execute()` call, for further execution of sql statemenet.

Comment: @RahilWazir You mean like this - `$preparedStatement->execute();
$preparedStatement->closeCursor();` And after add the next update statement?

Comment: @RahilWazir How do I implent if else on execution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should become this and make sure you replace placeholder values in the second statement.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$cat = $_POST['cat'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

// first    
$sqlInsert = 'UPDATE article_cat SET cat=:cat, name=:name WHERE id=:id';
$preparedStatement = $db->prepare($sqlInsert);

// second
$sqlInsert = 'UPDATE article_posts SET cat=:cat WHERE cat = :_cat';

$preparedStatement->execute(array(':cat' => $cat, ':name' => $name, ':id' => $id));
$preparedStatement->closeCursor();

if (empty($name)) {
    echo'<div class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>Categorys name field is Empty!</div>';
} elseif (empty($cat)) {
        echo'<div class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>Categorys short name field is Empty!</div>';
} else {
    // second
    $preparedStatement = $db->prepare($sqlInsert);

    // second query statement
    if ($preparedStatement->execute(array(':cat' => 'set-your-cat', ':_cat' => 'where-clause'))) {
        $preparedStatement->closeCursor();

        echo'<div class="alert-box success"><span>success: </span>Category Updated!</div>';
    } else {
        echo'<div class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>Something went wrong while updating Category :/ ! Please try again.</div>';
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It gives me this - **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'**                That's on this line: `if ($preparedStatement->execute(array(':cat' => 'set-your-cat', ':_cat' => 'where-clause')) {`

Comment: @MeChris Need extra `)` parenthesis. Updated the code.